# Dataframe columns having individual indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have noticed an interesting behaviour which I haven't seen in the documentation:

Each column **inside** a dataframe can have its individual index!

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3, order='F'),
                  columns=list('abc'))

df
   a  b   c
0  0  4   8
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  3  7  11
```

Assign index to column `b`:

```py
df['b'].index = [-1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Different indices for different columns, but they all share the same dataframe index:

```py
df['a']
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int64

df['b']
-1    4
 2    5
 4    6
 5    7
Name: b, dtype: int64


df.loc[:2, ['b']]
   b
0  4
1  5
2  6

df.loc[:2, 'b']
-1    4
 2    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Is this described somewhere in the documentation?

Why can this be done in the first place? And can this be useful for something?

Comment: I didn't see it in the docs explicitely but each column of a dataframe is a **`Series`** and an series - by definition - can't be without an index. I don't know any useful application though.

Comment: thinking about the `loc` examples a bit, this seems to me more like a bug than intended behavior as it only works with number ranges, not for single indices (e.g. `loc[-1, ...`) (pandas version 1.4.3)

Comment: what do you mean share the dataframe index? It doesnt though? when you `.loc` column b all you get is the -1 row and 2 column which is the index for column b?

But yeah this is weird, no idea what case scenario this is useful for. But good to know nonetheless.

Comment: @Irsyaduddin, I mean that if you select like `df.loc[:2, ['b']]` or `df.loc[:2, ['a', 'b']]`, then the dataframe index (which is shared between all columns) is used.

Comment: I would argue that this is a bug. If you try to add an existing Series to a dataframe, there is an alignment of the indices and the locations where they don't match become `NaN`. So it makes sense that when altering the index of a series within a dataframe, this alignment should also be enforced. Maybe this is worth opening as an issue on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Answer (score 3):

**Is this described somewhere in the documentation?**

After an extensive look at [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html#api), it seems not.

**Why can this be done in the first place?**

Because of the existence of a cache, it seems. If I take your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3, order='F'),
                  columns=list('abc'))
>>> df
    a   b   c
0   0   4   8
1   1   5   9
2   2   6   10
3   3   7   11

>>> df._item_cache
{}
```

At first, the cache is empty. If you even just access a column, the series will be cached in.

```
>>> df['a']
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int32

>>> df._item_cache
{'a': 0    0
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 Name: a, dtype: int32}
```

Let's say we change index of series 'b', so now the cache looks like the following.

```
df['b'].index = [-1, 2, 4, 5]

>>> df._item_cache
{'a': 0    0
 1    1
 2    2
 3    3
 Name: a, dtype: int32,
 'b': -1    4
  2    5
  4    6
  5    7
 Name: b, dtype: int32}
```

When you access column 'b' through DataFrame's `__getitem__()`, here is how it seems to work.

```
key = 'b'
df._get_item_cache(key)
```

Specifically, in the source code, as `'b'` is a hashable type, it will return the cache of the actual series. If the type was not hashable (such as a list, `['b']`), then it would make a copy first, and make the cache irrelevant.

When you use .loc's `__getitem__()`, it works a bit differently. But in essence, it extracts the series with its cached index. However, not exactly sure about why `['b']` would show df indices in that case... There is more digging to make on that side.

**And can this be useful for something?**

Probably not. Although it could be used as a third dimension for your data, I guess, but there are other, more practical solutions existing I believe.

Comment: I agree that this seems to be a caching issue, where you're changing the index of the "view" `df['b']` _in cache_, but not propagating this index back to the original `df`. Also note how a direct change to the DataFrame, e.g. via `df.iloc[1,1]=12` will also reset/clear the `df._item_cache` thus a renewed `print(df['b'].index.values)` will then again (accurately!) return `[0 1 2 3]` instead of `[-1, 2, 4, 5]`.